# how to make a smooth region with shader

Tags: opengl, shader

I want to code a shader to clip a circle region by shader, but it seems not good, its edge isn't smooth, here is code:

vert file:

```
varying vec3 normal;
void main()
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0; 
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix*gl_Normal;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

frag file:

```
varying vec3 normal;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{

    vec4 clr = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    float s = gl_TexCoord[0].s - 0.5;

    float t = gl_TexCoord[0].t - 0.5;

    if ( s<0.0 )
        s = 0.0 - s;
    if ( t < 0.0 )
        t = 0.0 -t;
    if ( s*s + t*t >0.5*0.5 )
        clr = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);     
    gl_FragColor = clr; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a small blending between your two regions by mixing your two colors in the intermediate region.

```
varying vec3 normal;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{

    vec4 insideColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 outsideColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    float s = gl_TexCoord[0].s - 0.5;

    float t = gl_TexCoord[0].t - 0.5;

    if ( s<0.0 )
        s = 0.0 - s;
    if ( t < 0.0 )
        t = 0.0 -t;

    const float radius = 0.5;

    // scale represents the pixel width of the image.
    // I used an arbitrary value of 128px but you should set this to
    // the actual width.
    // The smaller this value, the larger the blending zone will be.
    const float scale = 128;

    float mixFactor = clamp(scale * (s*s + t*t - radius*radius), 0, 1);
    gl_FragColor = mix(insideColor, outsideColor, mixFactor);
}
```

Also, try not to use branching statements when writing shader and use vector calculus instead of multiple float operations. A more efficient (but that could still be improved) version of this shader would be:

```
varying vec3 normal;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{

    vec4 insideColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 outsideColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec2 coord = gl_TexCoord[0].st - vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    coord = abs(coord);

    const float radius = 0.5;

    // scale represents the pixel width of the image.
    // I used an arbitrary value of 128px but you should set this to
    // the actual width.
    // The smaller this value, the larger the blending zone will be.
    const float scale = 128;

    float mixFactor = clamp(scale * (length(coord) - radius), 0, 1);
    gl_FragColor = mix(insideColor, outsideColor, mixFactor);
}
```